# A person in charge of scheduling work-shifts

Tags: word-request

Is there a default/common word for that guy/gal who's in charge of building the weekly work schedules of others in their workplace? (Referring mainly to shift-based work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that task is the job of a **Personnel Manager** or a **Human Resources Manager**.